# What is the structure of the sentence The living be cursed?

Tags: phrase-structure

What is the usage of be here? Act as what element in the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2):

This is a (rare) example of a subjunctive clause.  The subjunctive isn't used in modern English, but it was part of older forms of English. The game that you have quoted this from (without attribution!) is using archaic grammar to sound "old and medieval".

In older forms of English, it might mean "The living should be cursed" or "The living might be cursed".  A modern reader probably understands it to mean the same as "The living are cursed" - but in an "olde worlde" way of speaking.